# What does the s mean in format=[%(name)s][%(levelname)s] %(asctime)s: %(message)s

Tags: python

In python's logging conf file I see the string:

```
format=[%(name)s][%(levelname)s] %(asctime)s: %(message)s
```

I can't find where the `%` constructs are documented, in particular what the `'s'` means.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#formatters

Comment: And https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @drum and @klausd:

- https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#formatters
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting

And the narrow answer to my question (as far as I can see) is that the

```
%(identifier)s
```

notation is one of three ways to format logger messages. This particular one, I think is unique to logging and it has %(identifier) to refer to a specific field in the dict for the logger and the `s` one of many conversion codes, this one meaning "string".